# What size are the Gale Force 9 spellbook cards?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I'm intending to buy the [cards](http://www.miniaturemarket.com/gf973904.html) and put them in a folder giving the feeling of being a spell book like this one:

[image]

http://www.miniaturemarket.com/gf973904.html

I can't figure out from any source if their format would fit into theese sleeves. Can anyone give feedback about this working?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The cards are 2.5 inches by 3.5 inches, standard playing card size.

Source: I measured one.

Comment: ... conclusion?:D

Comment: @Zaibis I have no idea what card folder you're looking at buying. I imagine wherever you're buying it from will say what cards it fits somewhere.

Comment: Then I'm interested in what standard your "stadard" playing card size. is refering to. I was thinking of the typical ultra pro card sleeves designed for magic or pokemon cards (as both is from wiazrds of the cost it isn't that far away to assume cards as tool for another product of Wotc, will have the same format but I would like to be sure about.)

Comment: @Zaibis 5 second Google says M:tG cards are also standard playing card size, 2.5 inches by 3.5 inches.

Comment: Yep, the common card sleeve and card page size is for 3.5″×2.5″ cards. Source: many years owning and storing way too much MtG cardboard.